# Full Git Integration in Visual Studio

Tags: git, visual-studio

I am using Azure Devops and have created 2 projects that use TFS as the source control provider and 1 project that uses Git as the source control provider.

With the 2 TFS projects I can connect to them in Visual Studio in "Manage Connections" and click on them and then click on "Source Control Explorer" to see what files are on the server for that project.

With the 1 Git project I can connect to it in Visual Studio in "Manage Connections" and then click on it but there is no "Source Control Explorer" so I cannot see what files are on the server for that project.

My question is, how can I see what files my Git project has on the server?

Comment: There's no built-in repository viewer for git.

Comment: @Stijn Is there an extension or something I can download?

Comment: None that I'm aware of. Azure DevOps itself has a repository browser that you can use, in the left menu go to *Repos -> Files* and choose a repository.